# How do I correct this filecount?

Tags: php

Although this is more of a generic php question than specifically WordPress, it relates to a function used in WP and so I've posted here.

I use the code below to provide a count for the number of article authors (there's one jpg per author in a folder).

The published count is one more than actual... currently, for 53 jpgs it shows 54.

```
function item_count() {
$dir = 'PATH TO FOLDER';
$filecount = 0;
$d = dir( $dir );
while ( $f = $d->read() ) {
if ( ( $f!= "." ) && ( $f!= ".." ) ) {
if( ! is_dir( $f ) ) {
$filecount++;
}}}
return '' . $filecount . '';
}

add_shortcode( 'count', 'item_count' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - this is very much a generic PHP question. But fwiw, the issue is that you clearly want to count all *JPEG* files, but your sample code counts *all* files - so...

```
while ( false !== $f = $d->read() ) {
    if ( in_array( strtolower( pathinfo( $f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ), [ 'jpg', 'jpeg' ] ) )
        $filecount++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, your code is a useful improvement. Appreciated. (I since found that the cause of my issue was that having experimented with a script to display all images within that directory, although I'd removed the script I hadn't realised it had created a sub-directory of thumbnails - which was causing the count error.)